# Cloudflare | Getting 522 Connection Error

Tags: heroku, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

I have my domain purchased at GoDaddy and the code lies on heroku.com's hosting. I have my account on cloudflare also, on which I was provided with the name servers to insert in place of godaddy's name servers. 
My Primary need is free SSL certificate on my site www.koalastore.in, but whenever I open " https://koalastore.in " I have been shown the error as mentioned in the image below [image]

Any troubleshooting for this problem ? Experts please help.

Thank You in advance. :)

Comment: "My Primary need is free SSL certificate on my site"—is this why you're using CloudFlare? Are you using a paid dyno on Heroku? If you are you can get free SSL from Heroku and Lets Encrypt.

Comment: No, I have free dynos on Heroku and want a free SSL from cloudflare.

Comment: First of all, `koalastore.in` and `www.koalastore.in` are different things. The former doesn't appear to be pointing to your Heroku app. Try updating your CloudFlare settings to use `www.koalastore.in`. Secondly, I'm pretty sure your DNS needs to point to _CloudFlare_, not Heroku, if you want to use CloudFlare SSL.

Comment: Finally, Heroku's free dynos go to sleep regularly and take some time to wake up. Some requests to your site could easily take 15–30 seconds to get a response. That probably isn't what you want, and the only solution there is to upgrade to a paid dyno. If you're going to do that you might as well use Heroku's ACM feature.

Comment: I have paid Dynos and I have the same issue

Comment: I don't know if anyone else is in the same boat here, but assuming that you're using Heroku for the free tier, you might also have dabbled in AWS free tier. I had for some reason added AWS A records, and my 522 errors went away when I switched those for an `@` CNAME record pointing back to Heroku DNS host. Rebuild your A and CNAME records in Cloudflare just to make sure.